# SQL Different Group By Levels within one query

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I try to get a percentage of one dimension grouped by another dimension. So say I have

```
table1 =
country, product, sale
US, TV, 50
US, TV, 150
MEX, TV, 50
US, PC, 800
```

I wanne group by product in country and get:

```
Select... =
Country, Product, Country_Total, Product_Per_Country, Percentage
US, TV, 1000, 200, 20%
US, PC, 1000, 800, 80%
MEX, TV, 50, 50, 100%
```

I would like to select from table1 only once as this is an expansive select. Can you help out?

Many Greetings,
Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use window functions:

```
select country, product, sum(sale) as sales,
       sum(sale) / sum(sum(sale)) over (partition by country) as country_ratio
from table1 t1
group by country, product;
```

Answer (score 2):

try like below using window function

```
 select country, product,sum(sum(sale)) over( partition by country) Country_Total,
sum(sum(sale))over( partition by country,product) Product_Per_Country,
 (sum(sum(sale))over( partition by country,product) /sum(sum(sale)) over( partition by country))*100 as Percentage
from cte group by country, product


COUNTRY     PRODUCT     COUNTRY_TOTAL   PRODUCT_PER_COUNTRY     PERCENTAGE
MEX         TV            50            50                      100
US          PC           1000           800                     80
US          TV           1000           200                     20
```

[online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=8c7547703442f4e5b3508540c136b046)

Answer (score 1):

Query is like

```
SELECT country, product, sum(sale) as sales,
sum(sale) / sum(sum(sale)) over (partition by country) as country_ratio
FROM table1
GROUP BY country, product;
```